# Dynamically load VMAP schedule in jwplayer?

Tags: xml, jwplayer, vast

[The jwplayer documentation](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1432026-vmap-ad-schedule) indicates that I can simply load a VMAP.xml file into the schedule field to control ad placement within the player. It's pretty simple to do.

```
jwplayer('videoplayer').setup({
        file:      'myServer/video.mp4',
        primary:   'flash',
        debug:     true,
        autostart: true,
        width:     480,
        height:    270,
        advertising: {
                client: 'vast',
                skipoffset: 0,
                schedule: 'myServer/VMAP.xml' ,
        }   
});
```

However, is it possible to generate VMAP dynamically and use that instead? I've tried replacing the `schedule` parameter with my script and it doesn't seem to work.

```
jwplayer('videoplayer').setup({
        ...
        advertising: {
                ...
                schedule: 'myServer/VMAPGenerator.js' ,
        }   
});
```

Where `VMAPGenerator.js` would take in some parameters and output a VMAP xml file. I've also tried to replace the segment with a variable..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myServer/VMAPGenerator.js"></script>
<script>
var VMAPxml = getVMAP();
jwplayer('videoplayer').setup({
        ...
        advertising: {
                ...
                schedule: VMAPxml,
        }   
}); 
</script>
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. Is this possible at all? If so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the dynamic behavior you're trying to achieve something that would be better suited for an ad server (versus within the player)? This documentation may be helpful: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1434340-ad-tag-targeting-macros. URLS can be dynamically generated if the VAST tags inside your VMAP utilize macros.

Comment: Yes, the script would be on the ad server side. Presumably, the page would send some information about the video content such as the length, and the placement of the ads, such as where the midroll ads would be, and a call to the ad server would be made which would return the VMAP. That document describes VAST, I just wasn't sure if a VMAP file would work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

JW Player reads the VMAP schedule and makes the call out to the ad server for each VAST tag. If you set the ad tags in your VMAP to grab the custom params from the page, they will work:

1. schedule: "vmap.xml"
2. [Set the macros on each VAST tag inside the
   VMAP](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1434340-ad-tag-targeting-macros)
3. Get your targeted tags

Comment: Right, I know I can set macros on the VAST tags inside the VMAP based on the custom params, but I'm more interested in step 1. schedule: "vmap.xml", I want that vmap itself to depend on the custom params, the VAST inside would be handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to load vmap file with .js extension and it loaded the ADS, setup is following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var player3 = jwplayer("player3").setup({
        file: 'http://images.alfa.lt/30262/64/71.mp4',
        primary: 'flash',
        advertising: {
            client: 'googima',
            admessage: 'Reklama baigsis po XX s',
            schedule: "google-vmap-long.js"
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is your .js file just a file with XML in it but with a .js extension? Or a js script that generates and returns an XML?